# signed .apk not installing on ARM11 (ARMv6) devices

Tags: android, armv6

An app I'm developing installs and runs fine on **ARM11 (ARMv6) devices** when I deploy via ADB or install the .apk that gets generated in **/bin**, however once I sign the .apk (using Eclipses 'export signed apk feature') the resultant .apk will not install on some devices.

By taking note of the processors used by devices for which it works and doesn't work, plus some searching and reading I've identified the problem seems to apply to ARM11 devices (i.e. ARMv6 processors).

I'm using **Proguard**, and at first assumed it was to blame, however I since bypassed any proguard shennanigans by commenting out the applicable line in project.properties - still the signed .apk won't install on those ARM 11 devices.

Have also noticed that the ARM11 devices are running Android versions no greater than 2.2.1, although I don't have any ARM11 devices running 2.2.2 or higher to verify if 2.2.1 is a part of the problem.

I'm **including 2 external jars** in the project, but the fact that the /bin apk installs and works suggests the jars aren't part of the problem.

Any knowledge you may have, or direction as to how I should hunt for a solution = **much appreciated!**

Comment: Check logcat while installing app, may be insufficient storage or any reason can be there.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention that logcat wasn't providing any info on the issue, only that the "application not installed" coincides with the log regarding (if I recall correctly) parsing the tmp file during installation attempt.

Comment: which libraries you are using? those might be causing issues.. are they compactible with android Dalvik VM?

Comment: The libraries are: spongycastle (latest unofficial release) and loopj...definitely compatible, although perhaps spongycastle isn't sociable with ARMv6 architecture..??

Comment: So yesterday I had attempted to build & install about 12 times, all of those builds were yielding "application not installed" on an HTC Wildfire yet did install on anything non-ARM11/Android2.2.2+. Today I am able to install the 11th and 12th builds from yesterday on the HTC Wildfire...

Comment: ...during those build attempts I had done things like bypass proguard and enhance proguard's cfg concerning the libraries. The 11th build had proguard bypassed, 12th build had proguard on...today I've rebuilt and reverted the proguard cfg a little so it allows the libraries to be obfuscated and that build is also installing. So, putting this one down to GREMLINS lurking somewhere within the combo of Mac+Eclipse+ADTv15+HTCwildfire. Solved by turning the Mac & HTC Wildfire off, going home and getting some sleep, then turning the Mac and HTC Wildfire on again the next day and trying again.

Answer (score 0):

Putting this one down to GREMLINS lurking somewhere within the combo of Mac+Eclipse+ADTv15+HTCwildfire. Solved by turning the Mac & HTC Wildfire off, going home and getting some sleep, then turning the Mac and HTC Wildfire on again the next day and trying again.